# Redirecting www to non-www with http to https redirect and wildard subdomains

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu

I just installed SSL certs but when visiting the www domain of my site it now shows the Apache2 Ubuntu default page. How do I redirect the www to non-www *with* http --> https and * subdomains?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName clearpath.site
        ServerAlias *.clearpath.site
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =clearpath.site [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =*.clearpath.site
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

And me VH for port 443:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerName clearpath.site
        ServerAlias *.clearpath.site
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example; I've always been explicit in listing my subdomains, but you should be able to use wildcards: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serveralias

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com subdomain.example.com other.example.com
  Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  TimeOut 300
  SSLEngine On

  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com subdomain.example.com other.example.com

  # Set to the lobal Application Group
  WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
  # Pass Authorizations through to the WSGI app for Django REST Framework Token Auth
  WSGIPassAuthorization On

  WSGIDaemonProcess mysite-master-https python-home=/path/to/django/mysite-master/venv request-timeout=300 user=apache group=apache processes=6
  WSGIProcessGroup mysite-master-https
  WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/django/mysite-master/config/wsgi.py process-group=mysite-master-https
  <Directory /path/to/django/mysite-master/config>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  Alias /static/ /path/to/django/mysite-master/static/
</VirtualHost>
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hi and thank you for the response! As for the wildcard subdomains, they are required in this project as I won't know the subdomains of each tenant and cannot manually update this. Can you tell me what this means: `Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/`? And why is your VH :80 so short compared to mine?

Comment: Sure! `Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/` means to "redirect" all incoming requests on port 80 http for the servers list above. "permanent" means to use a 301 permanent redirect, versus a 302 temporary redirect (search engines will update). `/` means the root of the site, and `https://www.example.com` is where to redirect to.

Comment: As for why my port 80 virtualhost is shorter: (1) I'm not logging anything. (2) I'm using Apache's redirect for all traffic, rather than trying to use `mod_rewrite` for a regular expression. It keeps it more straightforward, and there's no need for a `DocumentRoot` since we're just redirecting, not delivering any HTML pages from port 80.